# Bind Data in Gridview Without entering in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to Bind Data Inserted through any Registration Form in Grid-view.
BUT, their is No DATABASE. We Don't have any Database, So No data is Stored to retrieve. How can i Do this..???

Answer (score 1):

```
    //declare a datatable
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));

    //fill it with data
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["id"] = 1;
    dr["Name"] = "Name"
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    //set the datasource and bind the grid view
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```